# Trigger a Google Sheets popup if string is found anywhere within spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**The short question:**

I have the following script (note, it may not be the prettiest, but it works - for now):

```
var message = 'There is an allocation error';
var title = 'Alert!';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(message, title);
}
```

Currently, for obvious reasons, this triggers when the spreadsheet finishes opening. What I want is to have the script trigger based on if the string "#REF!" appears anywhere in the document. Bonus points if it can also advise the user on which sheet contains the string.

**The longer question:**

The use case is that the document is being used to allocate attendees to an event into various groups. Each group has a different maximum number of attendees before it is maxed out. There is a sheet called 'Groups' that uses:

`=query('Allocation Master'!A2:N, "select B, C, D, E, F where N = 'GROUP-01'")`

GROUP-01 can have a maximum of four participants. The group allocation sheet has the above formula in (say) cell A1. In A5 a similar formula exists for GROUP-02. If the 'Allocation Master' sheet has too many people allocated to GROUP-01 then a #REF! error is produced saying that the array was not expanded because it would overwrite existing data. This is great! But what I would love is to have the above popup produce when the user allocates the fifth person.

Comment: Check out https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57204 (similar qusetion)

Comment: Could you please add a sample sheet to see clearer what you want to achieve?

Comment: Your code snippet seems incomplete. When/how is this code snippet run?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can do this with a `TextFinder` and looping through all sheets.*

#### Code Example:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    let tf = sheet.createTextFinder("#REF").findAll();
    if (tf.length > 0) {
      var message = 'There is an allocation error on sheet ' + sheet.getName();
      var title = 'Alert!';
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(message, title);
    }
  });  
}
```

**Rundown of this function:**

- Get all sheets in active Spreadsheet
- Loop through sheets and search for the string `#REF` in all cells
- If a cell with this value is found, create a toast with the Sheet name in it

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)